# non-parametric statistical testing is better than the parametric one?

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, nonparametric

Conduct both a parametric and a non-parametric test for the median value of 80. Are the results from both the tests similar?
My code is:

```
Ins <- diabetes$Insulin

tstat <- median(Ins)

f1 <- function()
{
    x <- rnorm(length(Ins), mean = 80, sd = sd(Ins))
    return(median(x))
}

sdist <- replicate(10000, f1())

plot(density(sdist))
abline(v = tstat, col = "red" )

gap <- abs(mean(sdist) - tstat)
abline(v = mean(sdist) + c(-1,1) * gap, col = "blue")
s1 <- sdist[sdist <(mean(sdist - gap)) | sdist >(mean(sdist + gap))]
pvalue <- length(s1) / length(sdist)

# Non-parametric statistical testing
tstat <- sum(ifelse(Ins > 80, 1, 0))

# Describe the population and generate one synthetic sample
f1 <- function()
{
    v <- c(0,1)
    p <- c(0.5, 0.5)
    x <- sample(size = length(Ins), x = v, prob = p, replace = T)
    return(sum(x))
}

# Create sampling distribution

sdist <- replicate(10000, f1())

# Plot sampling distribution & create p-value
plot(density(sdist))
abline(v = tstat, col = "dark red" )

# Gap
gap <- abs(mean(sdist) - tstat)
abline(v = mean(sdist) + c(-1,1) * gap, col = "dark orange")
s1 <- sdist[sdist <(mean(sdist - gap)) | sdist >(mean(sdist + gap))]
pvalue <- length(s1) / length(sdist)
pvalue
```

First, my problem is the abline didn't show in both the parametric and non-parametric graph. I double checked my code and still can't find the reason.

Also, the non-parametric method is very powerful, it basically can be applied to all kinds of hypothesis testing problem, even though the distribution of which is not known. Does it mean the non-parametric method is better than the parametric one?
Thanks!

Comment: This really doesn't belong on Stack Overflow. It is more of a math/stats question. You should post it on such a site. Briefly: nonparametric tests have less statistical power but make fewer assumptions. If the assumptions behind a parametric test is valid (e.g. data drawn from a normal population) then you should go with a parametric test. If those assumptions are false (or at least if you have doubts about them and are trying to be as cautious as possible) then use a nonparametric test. With a nonparametric test you are less likely to be misled but more likely to miss a genuine effect.

Comment: I cannot access diabetes$Insulin ... so I cannot answer your abline problem. Regarding your which is better. That depends. Parametric tests will tend to have assumptions about the data, normality being a common assumption. However, there are assumptions for non-parametric tests as well, say independence. If your data fully meet the assumptions of a parametric test, then the parametric test would tend to be more powerful. The nonparametric test would tend to be more 'robust' in that it can be applied to more cases of less well behaved data